# How to best handle exceptions of the same type but different exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net

So I am facing the issue that I have to handle two different `System.InvalidOperationException`s differently. The `HResult` is the same because the type is the same and so far it seems the only difference is the message.

But I don't want to make a string check on the `message` as this seems very error prone, it also wouldn't work when our clients use different languages.

There is no `inner exception` either to identify those.
So what's the actual approach to this?

Here is the example:

```
try
{
   ExecuteSomething();
} 
catch (InvalidOperationException e) //Both are from signalR
{
   if (e.message.Contains("Connection started reconnecting before invocation result was received")) //do A
   if (e.message.Contains("The connection has not been established.")) //do B instead
}
```

Comment: Are they both coming from the same method? Can you give us more context please?

Comment: From what code do the exceptions originate? An external library or your own? Can you provide a dump of the exception details debugging output?

Comment: added more details!

Comment: Small hint for the catch statements: You could use the contextual keyword `when` for your catches. See [when contextual keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when).